# Using a Loop to count number of days between TODAY() and date in a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Semi-new to VBA but need help.  I have the following code that I am trying to convert into a loop to provide the number of days between today's date and a date found in column A. The number of rows can change based on data entered and want it to stop when the cell in column A is blank. I also want only the value to appear. Any help is greatly appreciated. The below works great for the first row. I believe the loop should appear on row 2 but don't know how to go about it. Thank you in advance.

```
Range(ActiveSheet.Range("E2"), ActiveSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(TODAY()-OFFSET(R2C1,0,0,COUNTA(c[-4]),1))"
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a loop for this. This will determine the used range in `Column A` and apply the formula (but only paste value) in the same used range down `Column E`

Also, notice that you do not need to use `.Select`, `.Active`, or `.Selection`. here. Directly qualify your ranges and you will save yourself trouble down the road. For learning purposes, it is best to act like those lines do not exist :)

---

```
Sub DateDif()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LRow As Long: LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range("E2:E" & LRow)
    .Formula = "=NOW() - A2"
    .Value = .Value 'If you want the formula to remain, remove this line
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that it is changing cell E1 which is the header column to a numeric number if E2 is blank. The code is to run when the person opens up the document or moves to another tab which functions fine. I don't see why the code is looking at E1. Also do not want to show a value at all if the worksheet is blank. How can that be adjusted?